# Reusing Partial Implementations from Abstract Base Class

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, subclassing

Consider the following abstract base class:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Optional

class Base(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def index(self) -> list[str]:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self, *, key: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs) -> None:
        # pre code that all subclasses should execute
        print(f"Loading {key=}")

        # Case-specific code that all subclasses should execute
        if key is None:  # key=None ⇝ load everything
            for idx in self.index:
                self.load(key=idx, **kwargs)
            return

        # case key ≠ None ⇝ This is what the user needs to implement
        raise NotImplementedError

        # post code that all subclasses should execute
        print(f"Finished loading {key=}")
```

What is an elegant way to implement such an abstract base class?

Currently, I am using the pattern shown below, which I find to be awkward because it forces one to implement a function with a different name than intended. Is there a way to avoid this renaming? I would prefer if `load` was the abstract method and all the magic stuff hidden in private `_`-methods. Towards this end, I was toying around with `__init_subclass__`, which enabled me to move the pre- and post-code to private methods, but it seems I cannot deal with the case specific code this way.

In particular, I would be interested in a solution that gets rid of the `**kwargs` in the base class. (Subclasses might add additional key-word parameters with defaults to `load`!)

```py
class Base(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def index(self) -> list[str]:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def _load(self, *, key: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        ...

    def load(self, *, key: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs) -> None:
        # pre code that all subclasses should execute
        print(f"Loading {key=}")

        # Case-specific code that all subclasses should execute
        if key is None:  # key=None ⇝ load everything
            for idx in self.index:
                self.load(key=idx, **kwargs)
            return

        # case key ≠ None ⇝ This is what the user needs to implement
        self._load(key=key, **kwargs)

        # post code that all subclasses should execute
        print(f"Finished loading {key=}")
```

Comment: This design seems backwards – usually subclasses of partial classes call *down* to the base class implementation, not the other way around. Do you need the "post code" in practice?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The post code is the least important part for sure. Currently, I am just using it to automatically add some logging.